# ORACLE: Creating unique values without using sequence while multi-inserts

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a parent table (`MAIN_TABLE`) and need to do multi-inserts into a child table(`CHILD_TABLE`) 
for various types (TYPE_1/TYPE_2/TYPE_3 etc).
That is for single parent record I will have three childs if there are three types.

```
WITH MAIN_TABLE AS 
(
    SELECT 100 AS ID,'RICK' AS NAME,5 AS LINE FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 101 AS ID,'TOM' AS NAME,6 AS LINE FROM DUAL
    )
SELECT * FROM MAIN_TABLE;
        ID NAME                       LINE
---------- -------------------- ----------
       100 RICK                          5
       101 TOM                           6

2 rows selected.
```

Need to insert parent record into the child table where for the line `column` it has to be populated in the increasing order.

```
INSERT ALL
  INTO CHILD_TABLE(ID, NAME, LINE, TYPE) 
    VALUES (ID, NAME, LINE, 'TYPE_1')
  INTO CHILD_TABLE(ID, NAME, LINE, TYPE) 
    VALUES (ID, NAME, LINE, 'TYPE_2')
  INTO CHILD_TABLE(ID, NAME, LINE, TYPE) 
    VALUES (ID, NAME, LINE, 'TYPE_3')
  INTO CHILD_TABLE(ID, NAME, LINE, TYPE) 
    VALUES (ID, NAME, LINE, 'TYPE_4')
SELECT ID, NAME, LINE
  FROM MAIN_TABLE;  

SQL> SELECT * FROM CHILD_TABLE
       100 RICK                          5 TYPE_1    
       101 TOM                           6 TYPE_1    
       100 RICK                          5 TYPE_2    
       101 TOM                           6 TYPE_2    
       100 RICK                          5 TYPE_3    
       101 TOM                           6 TYPE_3    
       100 RICK                          5 TYPE_4    
       101 TOM                           6 TYPE_4    

8 rows selected.
```

Here, instead of 5,6 as the line, I need to have 5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12.
How to go about this?

Note: 1. I cannot create sequence 2. No multiple separate inserts statements if possible.

Comment: Why can't you create a sequence? If you have the privileges to insert data you should be able to create a sequence. They are different privileges but you should ask your DBA to give you both :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I certainly hope this is a homework assignment:

```
INSERT INTO CHILD_TABLE
SELECT m.ID,
       m.NAME,
       o.MIN_LINE + ROWNUM - 1 AS LINE,
       t.TYPE
  FROM MAIN_TABLE m
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT MIN(LINE) AS MIN_LINE FROM MAIN_TABLE) o
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'TYPE_1' AS TYPE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
              SELECT 'TYPE_2' AS TYPE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
              SELECT 'TYPE_3' AS TYPE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
              SELECT 'TYPE_4' AS TYPE FROM DUAL) t;
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3778017de1035bc654c2e350a727825b)

Comment: @@Bob, the thing here is I need to get the sequence or ordering while inserting into the child_table but not after inserting into it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend using an Oracle sequence whenever its possible to. If you still feel the strong need for not using a sequence then try building pseudo-sequence tables and write some PLSQL functions to perform the inserts by choosing the available sequence + 1.

Or you could do something like

creating a variable for your current max value and try to use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column_name)+@your_var` where `@your_var= SELECT MAX(column_name) FROM child`